# terminal window appears after login?

Tags: command-line, wine, login, desktop-environments

04.4LTS VERSION

My system works fine but yesterday I just reinstalled Wine and in the process of installing it started responding slowly as I am unaware of that situation,started pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> keys continuously and after a while it started working fine. Then I restarted it.

And when I did the restart, after I successfully logged in, a terminal window pops up instead of the desktop. What should I do to start my PC normally?

The problem persists after I shutdown and restart as well.
The commands are working fine when I typed in the terminal but I can't get my home screen and access it just like other PC.

I am new to Ubuntu!!!

Please provide step by step procedure.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: By `04.4 LTS` version, do you mean Ubuntu 10.04??

Comment: yes,its ubuntu 10.04

Comment: After logging into the 'terminal' have you tried running the command `startx`?

Comment: yes it showed like this...."x:user not authorised to run the xserver  aborting."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was happening, the package `ubuntu-desktop` wasn't installed so I typed this:

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

And that's it, Ubuntu booted up to the desktop and works like normal!

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

If that doesn't work, try typing the following command into the terminal:

```
unity --restart
```

This command will restore the Unity interface for Ubuntu and hopefully get you back up and running.

Note: Have you tried using guest mode?

Comment: I think the OP is talking about Ubuntu 10.04.4, possibly the server version. So no `unity`.

Comment: @edwin What makes you think it's the server version?

Comment: Well, I said it *might* be the server. The desktop version has reached its End of Life, so the question would be off-topic in that case. As for the assumption that the OP is talking about Ubuntu Lucid, it's due to the fact that `12.04.4` has not being released yet.

Comment: i tried ctrl+alt+f7 nothing happened and then i tried unity  restart it came lyke this "unity comand not found"!!!!

Comment: guest mode doest work!!!

Comment: @kdp Actually, try typing `sudo startx`

Comment: @GeekyGamer14 i tried typing [sudo startx] it showed lie this                                                                  "fatal server error:

Comment: @GeekyGamer14  [Fatal server error:                                                              server is already active for display if tis server is no longer running,remove/tmp/.x0_lock&start again                                                                 please consult the The x.org foundation support at [http://wiki.x.org]                                                       for help                                                                    ddxsiggiveup:closing log]

Comment: Is there Anyone who can clarify my doubt?????

Comment: @kdp Do `sudo rm /tmp/.x0_lock` and then try `sudo startx` again. Also, please wrap the terminal messages in `code quotes`.

Comment: @GeekyGamer14 I did the above commands and it showed me like this           "sudo:rm/tmp/.x0_lock command not found"                                                                      what should i do now?!

Comment: @kdp No, its not `rm/tmp`, put a space between `rm` and `tmp`.

Comment: @GeekyGamer14 Thank you,but I am afraid it didn't work.when I tried typing above given command it said "cannot remove /tmp/.x0_lock:no such file or directory".

Comment: problem solved #sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem: try reinstalling gnome with this command
Sudo apt install --reinstall gdm3 ubuntu desktop